# subract every column from each other in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

We have a `df` as dataframe containing n number of columns. I want to subtract every column from each other such as(n is number of columns) :

- If n =3 then new column formed = 3
- If n =4 then new column formed = 6
- If n =5 then new column formed = 10

  For eg: - Data set contains 4 date columns which are start date, end date, DOB and Date of promotion. Then you will form 6 new columns containing difference of these date by taking 2 date at a time. One of the new column would be DOB - end date.

Comment: Can you add an example of input, dataframe and expected output? Kindly give a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please elaborate your question. what do you actually want??

Comment: As I understand, you want to have a difference on each combination of columns in another set of new columns. You are more likely to get answers if you provide sample data set and the expected results appropriately.

Comment: I have edited my question with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for something like this - get the difference of each pair of columns into new columns for each pair

Considering a `pd.DataFrame` with 5 rows and 4 columns - A, B, C, D  - with all random values

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(5, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

For every pair of columns (get the pairs using `itertools.combinations()`, create a new column with the pair as the column name (or anything you want the new column names to be) and set the difference of the `tuple` as the value.

```
for comb in (list(itertools.combinations(df.columns, r=2))):
    df[comb] = (df[comb[0]] - df[comb[1]])

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   A  B  C  D  (A, B)  (A, C)  (A, D)  (B, C)  (B, D)  (C, D)
0  0  1  1  1      -1      -1      -1       0       0       0
1  1  0  0  1       1       1       0       0      -1      -1
2  2  4  0  2      -2       2       0       4       2      -2
3  0  2  4  2      -2      -4      -2      -2       0       2
4  4  1  3  0       3       1       4      -2       1       3
```

This works for any number of columns.

Comment: Yes, this is the exact and accurate solution. Thank You!

Comment: @HarshKothari Glad that I was able to help.

Comment: I have already upvoted your answer as if I don't have enough reputation it will not be shown.

Comment: Thanks and happy coding 